# JMeter: Assertion Failure Message is displayed for Response Assertion

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I am trying Response assertion for the first time, and below error is displayed:

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /(?is)<title>Management Information System</title>/
```

[image: message]

What could be the reason for such error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First assumption**: why do you need this `(?is)` bit? In "Contains" mode Response Assertion should work fine if you remove it.

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
>
> a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

**Second assumption**: the assertion as per your picture is being applied to **all** requests, if you want it to be applicable only to one of them move it to be a child of that particular request.

Comment: I had added it as a child of particular request but still I am getting the same Error. I already went through the link provided by you.

Comment: If so, have you tried to remove `(is?)` from your pattern?

Comment: Yes I did remove it. Also, I just changed "Apply to" as "Sub-samples" and got the result. Thanks a lot Dmitri!

Answer (score 3):

The `Assertion error: false` line means that no internal jmeter error occurred.

The `Assertion failure: true` line means that the assertion condition you set to be checked was false.

The `Test failed: text expected to contain /(?is)Management Information System/` line means that you set up the assertion to check if the target of the assertion (most likely the response body) matches to the regexp /(?is)Management Information System/ but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

In JMETER: There if you see 2 Response Assertion tab then remove one of those Response Assertion which is (Pattern to test) is OK 
Then try again it will work